# Iin objc s it ok to set nil to a property of a nil object

Tags: objective-c, null

If I have an object like

```
AType *object = nil;
```

and I set nil to the object property like

```
object.property = nil;
```

Is it completly fine to do that, or could I run in some problem with some particular case?

Comment: `object.property = nil;` is syntactic sugar for `[object setPropery:nil]`

Answer (score 1):

You can send any message to nil object, it's absolutely fine.